# Compensate drawing delay from the game logic updates

Tags: java, android

Now I have (1: the UI-loop, there my SurfaceView is placed), (2: a second thread, there the draw function from the UI-loop is called AND the update calculations from my Engine) and (3: the engine, there all the calculations stuff are).

Now I wonder how the best and smoothest way to do the SurfaceView independent from the actual frame rate. How shall I do so it will compensate if there is a low frame rate?

I think my current solution isn't enough, see code below.

Thread-class

```
//Constructor stuff....

int static delay = 0; /* My delay in milliseconds, depends most on
which sort of game I'm trying to make */
@Override
public void run() {
 while (state==RUNNING) {
       long beforeTime = System.nanoTime();
       engine.updateSprites(); //Update calculations from my engine

 //Rita
 Canvas c = null;
 try {     

       c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
       synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
           view.myDraw(c);    //My draw function
     }
 } finally {
     if (c != null) {
         surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
     }
 }

 sleepTime = delay-((System.nanoTime()-beforeTime)/1000000); /* 1000000 because 
 of the nanoTime gives us the current timestamp in nanoseconds */

        try {
            if(sleepTime>0){
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);          

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
        }

 }
```

Is this code enough to ensure the independent from low frame rate? If not, where is my way to go?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://dewitters.koonsolo.com/gameloop.html

This is one of the best short lessons I know. It shows 3 different ways to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Now is his recommended prediction / interpolation solution implemented in my code. I was forced to convert it from C++, to a similar piece of code that was Java based, and it worked! Thank you Warren!

Comment: Hm, I don't understand, why aren't you getting your bounty from me?

Comment: I think I get it in 5 days :) In this time, you can chose another answer if you decide it is better

Answer (score 2):

Now, I'm not experienced enough in this to give you a definitive answer, I'm sure someone will be along soon to give you that. In the meantime however, I will provide my thoughts:

So the question is how to make sure the SurfaceView appears nice and smooth, regardless of the frame rate?

For something like this, I believe a common implementation is to use [double/mulitple buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering)

Whereby you draw the frame in the background, and as soon as it is ready, you switch the new frame for the old frame.

So imagine you have two canvases A,B.

You display A to the user, while in the background you are preparing B. When the client requests a new frame, you either show them A, or if B is ready, you show them B.

Comment: Yes, the way to make the SurfaceView smooth regardless of the frame rate. The other option that you wrote, are not how Android works. Android Surface does not behave like the regular double buffering.

Comment: Oh ok, that's interesting. I found this reply: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/8d1243c33f9b7b6e?pli=1 which explained how the buffering works.

On that page, there's a suggestion of creating your own buffer, so that your Front/Back buffer is double buffered in the standard way. It requires an extra copy of the buffer size though, so it may not be ideal compared to your idea of adding a cycle delay.

Comment: Well, then I was wrong. But do you have any example of double buffering, for example "create your own buffer"? The question about delay is still left, though.